# Defcon 20 CTF VM Image

Tags: python, sockets, virtual-machine, ipv6

I can't seem to access the services.
Booted up the downloaded [VM image](https://s3.amazonaws.com/dc20-pcap/dc20-freebsd-i386.tbz) using VMWare Fusion (on Mac OS X 10.8.2)

`ifconfig` returns the following:

```
em1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=9b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM>
    ether 00:50:56:25:fd:9a
    inet6 dc20:c7f:2012:12::7 prefixlen 64 
    inet6 fe80::250:56ff:fe25:fd9a%em1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x3 
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
```

`[root@dc20 ~]# sockstat -6`:

```
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS      
root     cashew     1447  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:7979 *:*
root     cherry     1443  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:24359 *:*
root     coney      1439  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:65214 *:*
root     dealer     1435  4  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:8888 *:*
root     desheepd   1431  3  udp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:547 *:*
root     dog        1427  3  tcp6   *:3146                *:*
root     gallows    1415  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:6666 *:*
root     jerkin     1395  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:63715 *:*
root     mixology   1387  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:35575 *:*
root     nancy      1379  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:57554 *:*
root     nom        1370  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:7368 *:*
nssds    nssds      1366  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:54339 *:*
root     ocrd       1362  4  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:31967 *:*
root     parrot     1357  3  tcp6   *:5160                *:*
root     ralph      1353  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:57553 *:*
scool    scool      1349  3  tcp6   *:4637                *:*
root     semem      1332  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:6941 *:*
root     sshd       1316  3  tcp6   *:22                  *:*
tictactoe tictactoe 1223  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:25375 *:*
_ngircd  ngircd     1210  10 tcp6   ::1:6667              *:*
_ngircd  ngircd     1210  11 tcp6   ::1:6668              *:*
_ngircd  ngircd     1210  12 tcp6   ::1:6669              *:*
_ngircd  ngircd     1210  13 tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:6667 *:*
_ngircd  ngircd     1210  14 tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:6668 *:*
_ngircd  ngircd     1210  15 tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:6669 *:*
root     zul        1083  3  tcp6   dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:25201 *:*
root     syslogd    1057  6  udp6   *:514                 *:*
```

But i just can't seem to connect to any of the services of the form dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:, for example, being able to send/recv to/from the `semem` service running on dc20:c7f:2012:12::7, port 6941

I've tried elementary things like `ping6` and `telnet -6` and `netcat`/`nmap`, and also python sockets, but they can't seem to connect (timeout).

The other *: services run fine.

---

I've read from google search results that `dc20:c7f:2012:12::7:6941` means that the service is bound to the interface associated with the ipv6 address 'dc20:c7f:2012:12::7', ie. the (virtual) network interface `em1`, which is also known by an alternative address, so in order to be able to communicate with the service, I'd first have to create a socket, bind the socket to this address associated with the interface, and then send to the service from this interface, but trying that in code doesn't seem to work for me still.

Some guidance please? hopefully some socket programming in Python.

mirrored in [reddit comment](http://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/xiowh/defcon_20_ctf_unmodified_freebsd_game_vm_from/c6cpniz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `/etc/rd.conf`, replace this line: `ifconfig_em1="inet6 dc20:c7f:2012:12::7 prefixlen 64"` with this `ifconfig_em1_ipv6="inet6 dc20:c7f:2012:12::7 prefixlen 64"`

Then restart.

```
[root@dc20 ~]# ping6 -c 3 dc20:c7f:2012:12::7
PING6(56=40+8+8 bytes) dc20:c7f:2012:12::7 --> dc20:c7f:2012:12::7
16 bytes from dc20:c7f:2012:12::7, icmp_seq=0 hlim=64 time=0.290 ms
16 bytes from dc20:c7f:2012:12::7, icmp_seq=1 hlim=64 time=0.065 ms
16 bytes from dc20:c7f:2012:12::7, icmp_seq=2 hlim=64 time=0.070 ms

--- dc20:c7f:2012:12::7 ping6 statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/std-dev = 0.065/0.142/0.290/0.105 ms
[root@dc20 ~]#
```

Totally works.

Comment: alright, noted. I'll try it once I find my VM image back again. Have you also tried to interact with the existing services available, eg. `semem`, to try hack it?

Comment: Yeah,  I can connect and communicate to the services.  I'm working on ralph, but I have connected to semen.